# Where are the initialize methods for classes in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Where is the `initialize` method for classes created in in Rails?

For example, I can create a new class with the following code.

```
rails g model User
rake db:migrate
```

And now I have a `/models/user.rb` with a `User` class.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

But from studying Ruby, I though all classes need to be initialized with an `initialize` method.

```
class User
    def initialize()
    end
end
```

But I never see this in Rails. How does Rails get around doing this?

(Currently using Rails 4.)

Comment: Not all classes need to have an initialize method, only classes that will have instances of it. Also, you might notice that the models inherits from `ActiveRecord::Base`, so there's a big chain of classes when you have a simple model. Try inspecting those.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The class inherits from `ActiveRecord::Base`. https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb

This class includes a ton of other files. Including a module called `core`, which defines initialize.

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/core.rb#L312

So it does have it, but it is hidden away.

Answer (score 2):

The constructor is derived from module ActiveRecord Base class.

Documentation about [initializer](http://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/3.0.0/ActiveRecord/Base#initialize-instance_method).

> Constructor Details

`permalink #initialize(attributes = nil) ⇒ Base`

> New objects can be instantiated as either empty (pass no construction parameter) or pre-set with attributes but not yet saved (pass a hash with key names matching the associated table column names). In both instances, valid attribute keys are determined by the column names of the associated table – hence you can't have attributes that aren't part of the table columns.

Answer (score 2):

> But from studying Ruby, I though all classes need to be `initialized` with an initialize method.

You don't have to define an `initialize` method. This is a perfectly valid Ruby class:

```
class Foo
end
```

And of course, I can create instances:

```
foo = Foo.new
#=> #<Foo:0x007fa814243ad8>
```

But `Foo` does have an `initialize` method, it was inherited from `BasicObject`:

```
Foo.instance_method(:initialize)
#=> #<UnboundMethod: Foo(BasicObject)#initialize>
```

The default implementation however does nothing, it's an empty method returning `nil`.

Comment: So you never need to use initialize unless wanting to define default options or attributes?